# Convert nested loops and conditions to a list comprehension

Tags: python, list

Is there a way for list comprehending this condition set.

```
clamp_sel = list()
for i in range(0, len(clamp_normalized)):
        for j in range(0, len(clamp_normalized[i])):
                if clamp_normalized[i][j][0] < int(max_min_band[index_selec]):
                        clamp_sel.append(int(clamp_normalized[i][j][0]))
```

If it is single dimension list, I could set the condition in this way.

```
norm_sel = [i for i in normalize_data if i[0] > max_min_band[index_selec]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should translate directly into a list-comprehension:

```
clamp_sel = [int(clamp_normalized[i][j][0])
    for i in range(0, len(clamp_normalized))
    for j in range(0, len(clamp_normalized[i]))
    if clamp_normalized[i][j][0] < int(max_min_band[index_selec])]
```

The general rule is (see the [manual](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)) that you should write the list-comprehension in exactly the same order as you would do with a series of nested for loops and if-statements. The only thing you change is to replace the final `xx.append(yy)` with just `yy` at the front of the list comprehension. Also note that this is essentially one long expression that you could write on an extremely long line. Because of the enclosing `[]`, you can divide this expression over multiple lines, with arbitrary indentation.

If the list-comprehension is more *pythonic* than the original is a question of taste. In this case, the nesting is straightforward, so I would personally go for the list-comprehension. If it gets more complex, stick to the for-loops.

As thefourtheye shows, this example can be further simplified by replacing the use of `range()` with a direct iteration over your lists.

Comment: looks complicated, but a list comprehension none the less.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Can it be improved using lamda

Comment: @pistal I don't think so. You're doing a lot of looping, so yes, not much.

Answer (score 6):

If `clamp_normalized` is a list of lists, you can iterate without using `range`, unless you need the index.

```
clamp_sel  = [j[0]
                  for i in clamp_normalized
                  for j in i
                  if j[0] < int(max_min_band[index_selec])]
```